# Proof of cubic convergence Laguerre's method for complex roots

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods

Given Laguerre's method for finding the roots of a polynomial $p(z)$
$$
 z_{n+1} = \frac{n}{G \pm  \sqrt{(n-1)(nH - G^2)}},
$$
with
$G(z) = p'(z)/p(z)$ and $H(z) = G^2(z) - p''(z)/p(z)$ cubic convergence is typically demonstrated by rewriting the iteration in the form of
$$
 z_{n+1} = \frac{p(x)}{p'(x)}\cdot
      \left(
         \frac{1}{n}\pm\frac{n-1}{n}\sqrt{1-\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{p(x)p''(x)}{p'(x)^2}}
      \right)^{-1},
$$ or similar variations thereof where it can be readily shown that for the right choice of sign (+) and assuming the principle square root that the method converges cubically to simple roots.

When $p(z)$ is real the process of obtaining the above expression is simply a case of pulling a factor of $G^2$ outside of the square root.   However, in the case when $p(z)$ I am unsure of the legitimacy of this operation since $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b} \neq \sqrt{ab}$ for complex numbers.  Can anyone explain the relevant derivation/proof in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method uses in the denominator from the two numbers
$$
G\pm\sqrt{cG^2}
$$
the larger one. This is the same as choosing from
$$
G\pm G·\sqrt{c}
$$
the larger one. As the square root is defined as always having a non-negative real part, the larger variant of the last formula is
$$
G·(1+\sqrt{c}).
$$